# Circular reference exception in JSON.stringify method

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

I have try to stringify the object using JSON.stringify method but i got the circular reference exception.

I have use the code snippet like following scenorio.

```
var john = new Object();
var mary = new Object();
john.sister = mary;
mary.brother = john;

// This line causes a runtime error.
var error = JSON.stringify(john);
```

reference link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836474(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836474%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

In this link the solution privided as remove the circular reference. but in may case i want to use like above code snippet. Is there any other way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Well what exactly would you want the result to be? An infinitely long JSON string? Since it's a serialization, it certainly isn't going to be able to pass along a reference to the object.

Comment: It is not logically possible to serialize something with a circular reference. Removing the reference is the only solution.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question and I can imagine lots of reasonable ways to resolve this: the reference is rendered as null, or some special value, etc.  Here is one solution by Douglas Crockford: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js

Answer (score 2):

Above code is adding your object in a deadlock (Assume that John is waiting for Mary and Mary is waiting for John).  So when you are trying to serialize it, its showing you circular dependency error.

Above scenario doesn't seems to be possible as Parent/Child are creating bidirectional relationships.You need to remove the reference of one depadancy

Comment: Assumption for better understanding

Answer (score -1):

```
var peoples=[],person={};
person['name']='Adam';
person['sex']=1;
person['generation']=0;
person['tree']=[0,2,4];
peoples[peoples.length]=person;

person={};
person['name']='Eve';
person['sex']=2;
person['generation']=0;
person['tree']=0;
peoples[peoples.length]=person;
```

Now you have an array of objects like a sql data base.
Adam get married with peoples[2] and build the new tree 4. Adam and Eve are siblings because they have the same generation and tree number. Ups its incest but there was no way around.